# Rails 3 refactoring issue

Tags: refactoring, view, group-by, ruby-on-rails-3, helper

The following view code generates a series of links with totals (as expected):

```
<% @jobs.group_by(&:employer_name).sort.each do |employer, jobs| %>
    <%= link_to employer, jobs_path() %> <%= "(#{jobs.length})" %>
<% end %>
```

However, when I refactor the view's code and move the logic to a helper, the code doesn't work as expect.

view:

```
<%= employer_filter(@jobs_clone) %>
```

helper:

```
def employer_filter(jobs)
    jobs.group_by(&:employer_name).sort.each do |employer,jobs|
        link_to employer, jobs_path()
    end   
end
```

The following output is generated:

```
<Job:0x10342e628>#<Job:0x10342e588>#<Job:0x10342e2e0>Employer A#<Job:0x10342e1c8>Employer B#<Job:0x10342e0d8>Employer C#<Job:0x10342ded0>Employer D#
```

What am I not understanding?  At first blush, the code seems to be equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax worked as I hoped it would:

```
def employer_filter(jobs_clone)
    jobs_clone.group_by(&:employer_name).sort.collect { |group,items|
        link_to( group, jobs_path() ) + " (#{items.length})"
    }.join(' | ').html_safe
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, it is directly outputting to erb, in the second example it is returning the result of that method.

Try this:

```
def employer_filter(jobs)
    employer_filter = ""
    jobs.group_by(&:employer_name).sort.each do |employer,jobs|
        employer_filter += link_to(employer, jobs_path())
    end   
    employer_filter
end
```

Then call it like this in the view:

```
raw(employer_filter(jobs))
```

Also note the use of "raw". Once you move generation of a string out of the template you need to tell rails that you don't want it html escaped.

For extra credit, you could use the "inject" command instead of explicitly building the string, but I am lazy and wanted to give you what I know would work w/o testing.

Comment: Close.  It returns values like <a href="/jobs">Employer A</a> instead of the actual link.  I would be curious to see the .inject syntax.  Does an OrderedHash (of which this is one) support the .collect method?

Comment: what do mean by "actual link"?

Comment: Instead of the link, the anchor tag is displayed as described above--as text.  I think this is called 'escaped'.

Comment: OK, that worked.  Will you explain why a function doesn't work the same way as the logic embedded directly in ERB?  I have other helper functions that process arrays and work as I would expect: args.collect { |bucket| link_to bucket, jobs_path() }.join(' | ').html_safe  What's the difference?

Comment: "collect" returns the sum of everything you operated on ... "each" will act on each object but only return the last one.